# How to apply my sed command on the files resulting from grep filtering only

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I have crafted this `sed` command which looks to be working fine, only it's being applied to all the files in my directory :

```
find . -type f -name '*.js' -not -path './node_modules/*' -exec sed -i .bak -E '
1i\
const env = require('\''env-var'\'');
s/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])process\.env\.([[:alnum:]_]+) \|\| ([[:alnum:]_]+)($|[^[:alnum:]_])/\1env.get('\''\2'\'').default('\''\3'\'')\4/g
s/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])process\.env\.([[:alnum:]_]+)($|[^[:alnum:]_])/\1env.get('\''\2'\'')\3/g
' {} \;
```

I wish to apply those transformations only to the files which match this grep command :

```
grep -r "process\.env\." --exclude-dir=node_modules
```

I tried using the pipe but I can't make the two working together. What's the right way to handle it?

EDIT: I tried this

```
➜  app-service git:(chore/adding-env-example) ✗ grep -r "process\.env\." --exclude-dir=node_modules | sed -i .bak -E '
1i\
const env = require('\''env-var'\'');
s/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])process\.env\.([[:alnum:]_]+) \|\| ([[:alnum:]_]+)($|[^[:alnum:]_])/\1env.get('\''\2'\'').default('\''\3'\'')\4/g
s/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])process\.env\.([[:alnum:]_]+)($|[^[:alnum:]_])/\1env.get('\''\2'\'')\3/g
' {} \;

sed: {}: No such file or directory
```

I want only the files containing `process.env.SOMETHING` to be edited.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Work with pipes. `xargs` comes handy:

```
find ... -print |
   xargs -d '\n' grep -l 'regex' |
   xargs -d '\n' sed 'stuff'
```

> xargs: illegal option -- d

You can:

- install GNU xargs
- install GNU parallel
- write a bash loop to read the files line by line, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
- make sure your files do not have spaces or tabs or newlines *in filnames* and just remove `-d '\n'` option.

Comment: ➜  app-service git:(chore/adding-env-example) ✗ grep -rl "process\.env\." --exclude-dir=node_modules |  xargs -d '\n'  sed -i .bak -E '
1i\
const env = require('\''env-var'\'');
s/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])process\.env\.([[:alnum:]_]+) \|\| ([[:alnum:]_]+)($|[^[:alnum:]_])/\1env.get('\''\2'\'').default('\''\3'\'')\4/g
s/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])process\.env\.([[:alnum:]_]+)($|[^[:alnum:]_])/\1env.get('\''\2'\'')\3/g
' {} \;

Comment: xargs: illegal option -- d
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements] [-S replsize]]
             [-J replstr] [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs]
             [-s size] [utility [argument ...]]

Comment: you need GNU xargs for `-d` IIRC. If your file names don't contain white space then you can leave that option off.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to reverse order of commands. `sed` on filtered list of files.

Files filter is combination of `grep` filter on `find` filter: `grep -l "process\.env\." $(find . -type f -name '*.js' -not -path './node_modules/*')`.

```
 sed -i .bak -E '
1i\
const env = require('\''env-var'\'');
s/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])process\.env\.([[:alnum:]_]+) \|\| ([[:alnum:]_]+)($|[^[:alnum:]_])/\1env.get('\''\2'\'').default('\''\3'\'')\4/g
s/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])process\.env\.([[:alnum:]_]+)($|[^[:alnum:]_])/\1env.get('\''\2'\'')\3/g
' $(grep -l "process\.env\." $(find . -type f -name '*.js' -not -path './node_modules/*'))
```